# Can't load a local background image in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, background-image

I'm having some problems taking an image from my local machine with my React App.

I'm trying to take image like

```
style={{ backgroundImage: `url(../../assets/images/games/${img}))`  }}
```

But it's not working, and I don't understand why.

My file is located in

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\myreactapp\src\routes\GameSlider\index.js
```

And my images are in

```
 C:\Users\Me\Desktop\myreactapp\src\assets\images\games
```

This is how my `index.js` looks now (without imports):

```
const GameSlider = ( { key, id,  name, img, minPrice, maxSlots } ) => {
    return (
        <div key={key}>
            <div className="home-games">
                <div className="img" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(../../assets/images/games/${img}))`  }} alt="..." />
                <div className="price">
                    <IntlMessages id="gameSlider.startingAt" />
                    <p>
                        <span className="min">{minPrice}</span> 
                        <span className="per-slot">
                            <IntlMessages id="gameSlider.perSlot" />
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <span className="title">{name}</span>
                <div className="features">
                    <Col span={24} className="feature">
                        <Icon type="lock" /> <IntlMessages id="gameSlider.upTo" /> {maxSlots} <IntlMessages id="general.slots" />
                    </Col>
                </div>
                <Link to={`/order/${id}`}><Button className="comet-buy-button" style={{ background: 'rgb(241,89,89)', borderRadius: '20px' }}>BUY NOW!</Button></Link>
            </div>
        </div> 
    );
}

export default GameSlider;
```

Comment: The url in your question should work, but the url in your code block is wrong, have you tried updating the url in the style tag to be: `url(../../assets/images/games/${img}))`?

Comment: Yes I can see that, but now is just like in full code (index.js), but still don't work

Comment: Have you tried debugging this in the DevTools of your browser (I prefer Chrome DevTools)? Doing that, you would be able to check and see if the computed url is correct (i.e. what is the value of `img`?) and whether or not your browser is able to resolve the url.

Comment: Yes when I inspect element on image it gives me "  background-image: url("../../assets/images/games/cs16.jpg");   " this image is in that folder

Comment: are u using plain node.js or with any package?

Comment: When you hover over that url, in the DevTools, does your browser preview the image for you? Check the network tab to see if that url is being requested (that will help you verify the relative portion of the url). If the url is requested and image is downloaded by the browser, then the problem is likely a problem with your css, not loading the file.

Comment: Keep in mind that GameSlider is imported in /routes/Home/index.js

Comment: Yes, you are correct that the url must be relative to the url of the page in the browser, not the url of the source javascript file.

Comment: if you put your images folder in public folder you can get the image by just  ```url('/images/games/cs16.jpg')```

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

**1 - Import your img:**

```
import img from '../../pics/asteroids.jpg'
```

**2 - And then use it:**

```
<div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${img})`}}>Test</div>
```

*On your page this div will look like this:*

```
<div style="background-image: url(&quot;/static/media/asteroids.c8ab11b3.jpg&quot;);">Test</div>
```

Comment: Inline styles are bad. How do you do it using a separate CSS/SCSS/SASS file because `background-image: url(image.png)` doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

**Absolute path** and **relative path** is always one of the issue for developers to fix :P so there is a another way to solve this easily.

You can use something like this:

import the whatever image in the namespace

```
import backgroundImg from '../images/BackgroundImage.jpg';
```

then use it the element like this

```
 <img src={backgroundImg} />
```

let me know if this works.

Comment: Good idea! However, you'll need some sort of a plugin configured (like Webpack's file-loader) in order to do this.

Comment: if app is created using `create-react-app` then file-loader is already configured to import images as a module.

Comment: Yes, when I import it like this I can show image, but I'm taking a list from json, where is only for example csgo.png, and I can't import images like this. I tried and it's not solution, but thatnks anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use image or images without importing them, you should put your assets folder into the public folder and use them like below:

```
src='/assets/images/pic.jpeg'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried for hours lots of different solutions and in the end it came down to having quotes inside the url call, like this:

```
    `url('${ImportedImage}')`
```

Quite weird that this happened though because in previous projects it has always worked fine without the inner quotes (actually, I've noticed in the past that it worked with OR without the quotes). Only thing I've done differently this time is used the TypeScript template of create-react-app to set up the project.